# Having trouble getting horizontal 3 level css menu to show 3rd level proplerly. I have included html and css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menuitem

I'm having trouble creating the third level fligh out for a horizontal css menu. I've tried many different changes to the css to no avail. I have included the menu html and the css. What changes do I need to make to the css to have it work?

When 'ADD SCORES' is hovered over the 2 menus should show to the right

```css
#menu {
    background-color: #66A366;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 20px;
}
#menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Arial Narrow", "Myriad Pro";
}
#menu li {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Arial Narrow", "Myriad Pro";
}
ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
    font: bold 14px/18px sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background: #66A366;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:1000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li {
    background: #555;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #666;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}


ul li ul li:hover li{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

ul li ul li ul li{
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font: bold 14px/18px sans-serif;
    display: none;    
    position: relative;
    top: -48px;
    left: 154px;
    width: 120px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:1000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li>SCORES
        <ul>
            <li>ADD SCORES

                <ul>
                    <li>Level 3-A-1</li>
                    <li>Level 3-A-2</li>                                                         
                </ul>


            </li>
            <li>EDIT SCORES</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>PLAYERS
        <ul>
            <li>ADD PLAYER</li>
            <li>EDIT PLAYERS</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>COURSES
        <ul>
            <li>ADD COURSE</li>
            <li>EDIT COURSES</li>
        </ul>
    </li>           
    <li>ADMIN</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want your menu to look like?

Comment: What I was looking for was to have the 'Level 3-A-1' and 'Level 3-A-2' items shoot out to the right of the 'Add Scores' menu item.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://codepen.io/DanielTate/pen/tFoeI

Do you have an example of what you want to achieve

Comment: I see your example and thats not what I'm looking for. I don't know how to load it into a fiddle example. I have the html and css above ready to show you. Under the first menu item user hovers over and below shows the 2nd menu item and from there when the 2nd menu item is hovered over a menu item becomes visible to the right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a 3rd level to my CSS drop down menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359829/how-to-add-a-3rd-level-to-my-css-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qdoan/FeYdA/)**

I'm not sure how you want your menu to look like, but I noticed that you forgot to wrap the tabs inside a `<ul></ul>` tag.

If you do that, the menu will look and behave like what most users would expect.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul> <-- here
       <li>SCORES
        // some code     
        <li>ADMIN</li>
    </ul> <-- and here
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I did forget the ul tags. What I was looking for was to have the 'Level 3-A-1' and 'Level 3-A-2' items shoot out to the right of the 'Add Scores' menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your time using Swimbi - Swift Menu Builder
- http://f-source.com/swimbi/
have a look at [menu demo](http://f-source.com/swimbi/demo/?menu=Business_Violett)